# Going to home page doesn't load the page in Polymer

Tags: polymer

When I go back to the home page(Either by Clicking on the home page icon or using back button) the constructor/ready methods are not beings called meaning that page is not loaded. It is loaded only once i.e either on refresh or when I enter the url again. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a page loads one time. If you want a way to check if page is now in view, you can try adapting the `_visibleChanged` observer from [the Shop app](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/case-study).

Comment: Did you mean '_pageChanged'? If I was doing something on the other page and go to home, the action that I was doing is still active in the sense that when I click on the button, its still showing the same. How to make sure that this doesn't happen.

Comment: I want to ensure that when I click on a page (apart from the home), it is reloaded and doesn't contain the previous actions.

Comment: Yes, sorry. `_pageChanged` on changing the page. `_visibleChanged` for showing/hiding an element in a page. I believe you're going to have to stop the action and clear/reset the element yourself. For times when the page doesn't change (in my case, when I use `_visibleChanged`) I create the element with `new MyElement()`, and use `appendChild()` and `remove()` to add or remove the element from the DOM.

Comment: new Element() does reload it but the how can I go load the original state of the page